# shell command to create system v ressource key compatible to ftok system call

Tags: linux, shell

I'm working with system V shared memory in an application. during development I need to inspect and, sometimes, delete the memory segment. I know there is the `ipcs` command to inspect shared memory, and there is `ipcrm` to delete. My only problem is, I first need to look up the `shmid` of the shared memory segment using `ipcs -m`, identify the correct one, and then delete it using `ipcrm -m <shmih>`. In my application I'm using `ftok()` to identify the shared memory segment using a file and an identifier, which is much easier (one can use `ipcrm -M` to delete a shared memory segment using its key instead of shmid). Is there an `ftok` command for the shell? By default, my ubuntu server has none, and inpecting man files I didn't find any hint on one either.
A shell script or binary that creates the same IDs as ftok does is fine, too... I just don't want to use any other intperpreter than /bin/sh or /bin/bash for compatibility reasons. ANd I don't know too much C, so unfortunately I cannot just write my own.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is. I have never used it, but I kept the following reference for use, should need arise: [here](http://sabrela.com/?p=964). The title of the post,

**ftok in bash**

is self-explanatory. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link! unfortunately, the code there doesn'T really work. The outpuit doesn't fit the keys a system ftok() call creates. It's not completely wrong however, just slightly different... `ipcs -m` states, that the key for the shared memory I have is `0x6e4f0360`, while that ftok-implementation gives me `4f0360n`. But I have never seen a system V key with a letter in it... so maybe that was working for older/other versions of system v, but doesn't fit mine.

Comment: Looking closer at that code, it's obvious that that can't work, at least not on GNU Linux. The "n" in `fprint`s first argument is just output as-is, that's why I get the n there... and the generated hex number is too short to ever get 6e4f0360. WHen googling, I discovered some C source code that used the same generation, apparently from an apple binary. SO maye they're dogin things a little different. (the n in `fprint` may also work on apple's `fprint`, don't know)

Comment: Erm, nope, nevermind. Linux source is the same.